# knowing if the pseudopotential in the first step is correct via Haman procedure

Tags: pseudopotentials

## Context and objective

This post is a follow up from [here](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/12228/norm-conserving-pseudopotential-procedure). I want to generate a pseudopotential for a Carbon atom. So I want to pseudize the 1s electrons.

## Question

So $V^{\textrm{PS}}_{1l} = (1-f(r/r_{cl}))V(r) + c_lf(r/r_{cl})$ where $V$ is the resulting potential from an all-electron calculation that will not change during the calculation to find the constant $c_l$. Correct me if I am wrong, but I think $$V(r) = V|\Phi(r)\rangle$$ with

- $\Phi(r) = \sum_i c_i|\phi_i(r)\rangle$ a wave function where $\phi_i$ are Contracted Gaussians
- $V_{ij} = \langle\phi_i|V|\phi_j\rangle$.

Since I did an Unrestricted HF calculation, $V^{\textrm{PS}}_{1l}$ and $V$ depend on the spin. It will not be useful here. The SCF procedure below defines $c_l$ has the eigenvalue of a problem. As implemented in multiple eigen-solvers, I will get $n=N_{Contracted \_Gaussians}$ eigenvalues.

**How do you know that the constant $c_l$ has the right value? Maybe some intuition?**

## Derivation of the SCF procedure for $c_l$

From the Hartree-Fock equations, with the Lagrangian $\mathcal{L} = \langle\Phi^{\textrm{PS}}_{1s}|H|\Phi^{\textrm{PS}}_{1s}\rangle - \epsilon^{\textrm{AE}}_{1s}(\langle\Phi^{\textrm{PS}}_{1s}|\Phi^{\textrm{PS}}_{1s}\rangle - 1)$:
$$
H^{\textrm{PS}}_{1s}c^{\textrm{PS}}_{1s} = \epsilon^{\textrm{AE}}_{1s} Sc^{\textrm{PS}}_{1s} \tag{1}
$$
where

- AE means a quantity computed during the all-electron calculation
- $c^{\textrm{PS}}_{1s}$ the coefficients of the smoothed wavefuntion
- $H^{\textrm{PS}}_{1s} = T + V^{\textrm{PS}}_{1l} = T + \bar{FV} + c_l\bar{F}$
- $\bar{F}_{ij} = \langle\phi_i|f(r/r_{cl})|\phi_j\rangle$
- $\bar{FV}_{ij} = \langle\phi_i|(1-f(r/r_{cl}))V(r)|\phi_j\rangle$

Hence
$$
\begin{align}
H^{\textrm{PS}}_{1s}c^{\textrm{PS}}_{1s} &= \epsilon^{\textrm{AE}}_{1s} Sc^{\textrm{PS}}_{1s} \tag{2}\\
\left[T + \bar{FV} + c_l\bar{F}\right]c^{\textrm{PS}}_{1s} &= \epsilon^{\textrm{AE}}_{1s} Sc^{PS}_{1s} \tag{3}\\
\left[T + \bar{FV}-\epsilon^{\textrm{AE}}_{1s} S\right]c^{\textrm{PS}}_{1s} &= -c_l\bar{F}c^{\textrm{PS}}_{1s} \tag{4}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: +1 but please remove the MathJax from the table, add equation numbers for each equation, and use `\langle` and `\rangle` rather than `<` and `>`. Superscripts like `PS` would also look better using `\textrm{PS}`.

Comment: Ty, can u elaborate on the "please remove the MathJax from the table"?

Comment: Thanks for all of your corrections! I accidentally said "table" instead of "title". Please see [this](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/189/5).